# Store JavaScript Result In Php variable

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have Some Passwords which contain some special and methimatical chracters like this password "HHE1134ƒ" if i want to generate password with php md5() then this not give me correct hashes like this "679b6dc6122a9c83ed31476ee82af36e".

So i have Java Script which can generate correct hash for my passwords 
But how can i store this value to mysql

my code is given below please Help Me.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$user_id = $row['user_id'];
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
$lastname = $row['lastname'];
$spno = $row['spno'];
$password = $row['password'];

$tmp =  "<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(MD5('".$password."'));</script>";

$query1="UPDATE `wp_110504users` SET `user_pass` = '$tmp' WHERE `user_login` = '$user_id'";

mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

this will give me error like

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'text/javascript'> document.write(MD5('HW72'));' WHERE `user_login` = '0' at line 1
```

?>

Some one tell me use Ajax, Please tell me how can i use Ajax for this code can you give me an example .....

Comment: You know that your javascript-code is not going to be parsed and interpreted by the PHP interpeter?

Comment: U want add password in MD5 to database?

Comment: are you trying to implement client-side logic on server-side?

Comment: This gets asked a couple of times a week. Did you not think to search for existing questions first?

Comment: I've honestly never seen someone try to write a script tag that uses document.write to write an MD5 hash into a PHP variable to insert into a SQL query (by magic, since `$userpass` is never used). I don't think any search would pull this up, Tomalak.

Comment: @Dan: A search for "Javascript PHP variable" gives you 1,328 results, and all of them have at least one answer explaining the fundamental impossibility of doing what the OP is trying to do, bar separate requests.

Comment: BTW, [MD5 was cracked some time ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security). It is [no longer useful as a one-way encryption](http://www.md5this.com/). Store passwords crypted with some salt instead.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot run JavaScript code inside your PHP code on the server. The PHP interpreter only interprets PHP code.

You don't need to, both MySQL and PHP have `md5` functions to compute those hashes as well.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't run until it reaches the user's browser. This is called client side.

PHP is server side. All your PHP code executes before the web page is delivered to the user. Then your Javascript is executed on *their* own computer, by *their* web browser.

The only way to send something from Javascript to the server is using Ajax. You could look into it, but I don't think you should at your current experience level with the two languages. How long have you been using them for?

You can just use the md5() function which is built right into php btw: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: Yes you are right but i have some passwords which is not working with php md5 function like this password "HHE1134ƒ"

Comment: if you have any function to generate a correct like this "679b6dc6122a9c83ed31476ee82af36e" for this password "HHE1134ƒ" with php please tell me

Comment: when i type in php:
echo md5('HHE1134ƒ');
i get:
679b6dc6122a9c83ed31476ee82af36e
So where is Your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use php native md5 function:

```
md5($password);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is interpreted before javascript reaches the browser.
You cannot do this that way.
Read more about [AJAX](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=ajax%20php%20javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), this will help you.

BTW: why are you generating md5 hashes with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This is very normal, you `userpass` value will just be `<script type...`. Javascript is a  **client side** scripting language, whereas php runs **server side**, how would you want your md5 to be interpreted server-side?

What you can do, is hash the password before sending it, but it would make you trust the visitor, what you should never do, or simply use php function for md5 hashing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you copy-pasted code not correctly. According to error, you trying to put $userpass variable in SQL statement, but, in code, you are using $tmp variable, which is not defined at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$tmp = md5($password);
$query1="UPDATE `wp_110504users` SET `user_pass` = '$tmp' WHERE `user_login` = '$user_id'";
```

Also u can use MySQL function:

```
$query1="UPDATE `wp_110504users` SET `user_pass` = MD5('$tmp') WHERE `user_login` = '$user_id'";
```